# Convert GeoTIFF to NITF

Tags: gdal, geotiff-tiff, gdalwarp, gdal-translate, nitf

This should be very straightforward, but I can't seem to find this exact conversion scenario.  I understand pixel / row / and lat and long coordinates but it seems like none of these values agree with each other, nor is there information contained in the .tif metadata for 4 specific GCP, but many more, not just the corners. How is this supposed to run?

```
gdal_translate -of NITF image_HH.tif image_HH.nitf
```

outputs

```
Input file size is 132928, 13699
0...10...20...30...40...50...60...70...80...90...100 - done.
ERROR 6: The 4 GCPs image coordinates must be exactly at the *center* of the 4 corners of the image ( (0.5, 0.5), (13698.5 0.5), (132927.5 13698.5), (132927.5 0.5) ).
```

and

```
gdalinfo image_HH.tif
```

outputs

```
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: image_HH.tif
Size is 132928, 13699
GCP Projection =
GEOGCRS["WGS 84",
    DATUM["World Geodetic System 1984",
        ELLIPSOID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
        ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
    CS[ellipsoidal,2],
        AXIS["geodetic latitude (Lat)",north,
            ORDER[1],
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
        AXIS["geodetic longitude (Lon)",east,
            ORDER[2],
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
    ID["EPSG",4326]]
Data axis to CRS axis mapping: 2,1
GCP[  0]: Id=1, Info=
          (1,1) -> (111.069111116576,15.3557160509762,1.27591192722321e-07)
GCP[  1]: Id=2, Info=
          (132928,1) -> (114.68068434691,14.5410844662899,1.05239450931549e-07)
GCP[  2]: Id=3, Info=
          (1,13699) -> (110.903453210568,14.629538715478,1.08033418655396e-07)
GCP[  3]: Id=4, Info=
          (132928,13699) -> (114.503997460899,13.8200059186205,8.84756445884705e-08)
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
  TIFFTAG_COPYRIGHT=Copyright SSTL 2019
  TIFFTAG_DATETIME=2020:06:15 15:32:05
  TIFFTAG_IMAGEDESCRIPTION=16 bit Detected ScanSAR Product
  TIFFTAG_RESOLUTIONUNIT=3 (pixels/cm)
  TIFFTAG_SOFTWARE=Software Version: V1.13
  TIFFTAG_XRESOLUTION=0.0033333334
  TIFFTAG_YRESOLUTION=0.0016666667
Image Structure Metadata:
  INTERLEAVE=BAND
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (    0.0,    0.0)
Lower Left  (    0.0,13699.0)
Upper Right (132928.0,    0.0)
Lower Right (132928.0,13699.0)
Center      (66464.0, 6849.5)
Band 1 Block=132928x1 Type=UInt16, ColorInterp=Gray
```

Comment: Try `gdalwarp`ing your tif first.  You can gdalwarp to VRT first to avoid outputting an intermediate file.

Comment: What intermediate file? Shouldn't gdal_translate perform the entire transformation? The geotiff contains projection information and GCP data inside the metadata. Isn't that everything required?  Are you able to provide an example?

Comment: the -gcp flag seems to want 4 GCP locations, of which I've provided in numerous formats, including the output of gdalinfo, however nothing resolves this error/warning. The 4 GCPs image coordinates must be exactly at the *center* of the 4 corners of the image. I'm thinking I need to calculate the lat/lon at the center of each corner pixel? That seems like a bizarre calculation to require and this error genuinely makes no sense. If I run `gdalwarp -of GTiff -s_srs EPSG:4326 -t_srs EPSG:4326 -co ICORDS=G  image_HH.tif myNewFile.vrt` and then `gdal_translate -of NITF myNewFile.vrt image_HH.nitf`?

Comment: This really helped move things forward, thank you.  I am able to run the following `gdalwarp -of NITF -s_srs EPSG:4326 -t_srs EPSG:4326 -co ICORDS=D  split_a.tif split_a_D.ntf` with some success, however I am getting some poor resampling results.